# Oracle Sdo Circle_polygon query returns null

Tags: oracle, geospatial

Trying to follow the example in the Oracle SDO documentation for a circle polygon and constructed this basic query.

```
SELECT
SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON(
    SDO_GEOMETRY(
        2001,  
        NULL,
        sdo_point_type(
                -78.61414, 35.61105, null
        ),
        NULL ,
        NULL
    ),
    100,
    .05,
    -45,
    45 ,
    NULL,
    NULL
)
FROM DUAL;
```

The query returns null when I would have expected an SDO geometry object of type polygon. What am I missing?

Comment: which example can you add a link

Comment: [oracle example doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-56B42A45-B9BD-44FF-B5E7-EF7E9F089168)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the SDO_SRID for your point, Here's a test:

```
  1  SELECT
  2  SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON(
  3  SDO_GEOMETRY(
  4      2001,
  5      8307,
  6      sdo_point_type(
  7          -78.61414, 35.61105, null
  8      ),
  9      NULL ,
 10      NULL
 11  ),
 12  100,
 13  .05,
 14  -45,
 15  45 ,
 16  NULL,
 17  NULL
 18  )
 19* FROM DUAL
SQL> /

SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON(SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,8307,SDO_POINT_TYPE(-78.61414,35.61105
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 8307, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARR
AY(-78.61492, 35.6104127, -78.61487, 35.6103739, -78.614816, 35.6103378, -78.614
76, 35.6103046, -78.614702, 35.6102742, -78.614641, 35.6102469, -78.614578, 35.6
102228, -78.614514, 35.610202, -78.614448, 35.6101845, -78.614381, 35.6101704, -
78.614313, 35.6101598, -78.614244, 35.6101527, -78.614175, 35.6101492, -78.61410
5, 35.6101492, -78.614036, 35.6101527, -78.613967, 35.6101598, -78.613899, 35.61
01704, -78.613832, 35.6101845, -78.613766, 35.610202, -78.613702, 35.6102228, -7
8.613639, 35.6102469, -78.613578, 35.6102742, -78.61352, 35.6103046, -78.613464,
 35.6103378, -78.61341, 35.6103739, -78.61336, 35.6104127, -78.61414, 35.61105,
-78.61492, 35.6104127))
```